# java code style: returning specific Map implementation when generic contract is not sufficient

Tags: java

You have method, which returns Map. Returned instance is `LinkedHashMap`, because of necessity of predictable iteration order. I know that code-style requests that most generic type is used as return value type, which would suggest, that `java.util.Map` is used. However this contract is not sufficient in the context, as the code requires the predictability of order as requisite, not just some unimportant sideeffect of implementation. So therefore I'd think, it's OK and even correct not to return `java.util.Map` but actual implementation `java.util.LinkedHashMap` as this is least specific class bearing required contract, although no LinkedHashMap specific methods are used. What do you think? What is correct and what should be used in such situation?

*comment: yes, most of such usacases are just abuse of Map, and it should have been implemented as list of pairs or some similar structure. But abusing map is actually easier and "LOC-friendly". For the sake of question please assume, that it's not this kind of abuse, and Map has  true meaning here and has to be used. On the otherhand, if you know about readily available structure offering list of pairs(tuples) behavior with better than linear methods to get all i-th elements, please suggest.*

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use LinkedHashMap as the return type if this is the Map implementation that behaves as required? Everything doesn't have to be generic or always return an interface.

You said yourself:

> the code requires the predictability of order as requisite, not just
>   some unimportant sideeffect of implementation

In my opinion, just return LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that your method should return a `Map`, since `LinkedHashMap` is a specific implementation, so you don't want to force your method to always return a `LinkedHashMap`.

Your method should state in its Javadoc that the returned `Map` has an iteration order which is the same as the insertion order. This way it is allowed to return any `Map` implementation that fulfills this contract, and not just `LinkedHashMap`. Even if `LinkedHashMap` is the only implementation currently fulfilling this contract, that doesn't have to be the case in the future, and you don't want to prevent yourself from being able to change the implementation in the future.

Of course if would have been cleaner if there was a sub-interface of `Map` having the "iteration order the same as insertion order" contract, in which case you would have returned that sub-interface type instead of `Map`.

Comment: yep,if there is order-specific Map interface,it would be trivial.I understand the argumentation with changing the implementation,however it's not very likely that Map new impl. will occur and I would like to change this.But in principle you're correct. The question remains(for me) whether "valid in principle" approach justifies possibility to return non-iteration-aware implementation out of this method,which would be invalid. But on the otherhand one could return Collections.emptyMap,which is not-iteration aware by contract,but it's like that trivially.I'd like to hear others ideas as well

Comment: @MartinMucha Java can't enforce all contracts in compile time, so you don't have to do it either. Even if the return type of your method would be `LinkedHashMap`, you can still return a broken `LinkedHashMap` if the class of the key of your `Map` violates the contract of `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: yes,sure.I got it.It's more like a readability issue.Declaring it as that method return Map say,that it can return any map,however it really should not.It can be explained in javadoc as you suggested, the question is whether it's really sufficient.And yes,I understand that all static analysis tool will complain about usage of specific type,and it all revolves about absence of more specific interface than Map.I really don't know what is the correct way here, as both has some drawbacks, that's why I asked this question to have some criticism from multiple people and go with quorum solution